# powershell md5 compare too slow

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to compare several files using md5 hash with powershell 2.0.
The code works, the problem is that it's to slow.
It takes longer in step 3.
It's about 500 files to compare.
Can you see a way to get it faster, like, don't do the step 3 every time?

```
write-host "1"
    $COMP_ORI=$LOCAL_HOME+"\"+$PROG+"\"+$COMPARE
    $file_ori = Get-ChildItem -Path $COMP_ORI -name
write-host "2"
    $COMP_DEST="\\"+$HOSTIP[$i]+"\"+$PROG_PATH
    $file_dest = Get-ChildItem -PATH $COMP_DEST -name
write-host "3"
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $file_ori.Count; $i++) {
write-host "compare md5" $i
    if ( Get-ChildItem -PATH $COMP_DEST -name -Include $file_ori[$i] ) {
        $md5 = New-Object -TypeName system.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
write-host "4"
        $hash_ori = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($COMP_ORI+"\"+$file_ori[$i])))
write-host "5"
        $hash_dest = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($COMP_DEST+"\"+$file_ori[$i])))
write-host "6"
        if ($hash_ori -ne $hash_dest) {
            $out=$file_ori[$i]
            $out=$out+" IS DIFFERENT"
            output message_solo $out
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [codereview.se] is the stackexchange site for improving working code. You can try posting it there, but calculating md5sums is a pretty known algorithm, it is unlikely that you can speed that part up.

Comment: But you can probably speed up `Get-ChildItem -PATH $COMP_DEST [..]` by calling it once, and storing the results, then using `-contains` to test. Listing a remote file share 500 times won't be very fast. If you could get the remote server to compute the hash of the dest file with PowerShell remoting, that would save reading the file data over the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went for another approach since the problem wasn't the MD5 time.
I sent the 2 directories content into an array and then all the operation are made using those arrays.
The time went from about an hour to 10 min for 450 files.

```
$COMP_CS=$LOCAL_HOME+"\"+$PROG+"\"+$COMPARE
$FILE_CS=@(Get-ChildItem -Path $COMP_CS -name -exclude sqlnet.log)
$COMP_BASE="\\"+$HOSTIP[$i]+"\"+$PROG_PATH
$FILE_BASE=@(Get-ChildItem -PATH $COMP_BASE -name -exclude sqlnet.log)
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $FILE_CS.length; $i++) {
        if ($FILE_CS -contains $FILE_BASE[$i]) {
            $md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
            $HASH_CS = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($COMP_CS+"\"+$FILE_CS[$i])))
            $HASH_BASE = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($COMP_BASE+"\"+$FILE_CS[$i])))
            if ($HASH_CS -ne $HASH_BASE) {
                $out=$FILE_CS[$i]
                $out=$out+" IS DIFFERENT"
                output message_solo $out
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare files in chunks of, say, 4096 bytes.

1. read 4096 bytes from both files using [[IO.FileStream] class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx), for example.
2. calculate and compare md5
3. loop until the end of file is reached

I suggest comparing the first 4096 bytes, then last 4096 bytes, then proceed in linear fashion.
This is what I've done in a similar utility.

Finetune the number by trying various values.

Don't forget to compare file sizes firs: there's no need to calculate MD5 for files of different size
as it will be different.